# Android maven plugin runtime exception when executing tests

Tags: java, android, exception, junit, maven

I am new to the android maven plugin. I have created two test classes inside the application. One class extends **TestCase** and the other class extends the **ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2< MyActivity >**. When the project runs as the android JUnit test from eclipse all the test cases are executing fine. No errors. But when i try to build the project from eclipse it generates errors in the test classes.

However, 
In the class which extends the **TestCase** the test methods executes without any error through the maven also. But if i try to create an object of an activity it generates an error. 
ex: PINLoginController mActivity = new PINLoginController() - generates an initializationError.

And with the class which extends **ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2< MyActivity >** i get a runtime exception.

Exception in constructor: testPreconditions (java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Android test cases are designed to run within an Android emulator, so if you attempt to run them outside in a regular Junit test runner you'll get exceptions.

You might want to try this instead if you want to automate your tests:

http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/

Comment: Thanks Ricardo.. Will try that out.

Comment: No worries, feel free to up-vote my answer if you found it useful.